# Best way to loop through a string Array and Compare values with a List of objects?

Tags: c#, lambda

Still learning C# - is it possible to loop through elements of a string array and compare it with the values in a list of objects? eg:

```
var allFolks = new List<Folks>();
allFolks = Folks.GetAll();
string[] enteredNames = Array.ConvertAll(inputNames.Text.Split(','), p => p.Trim());

foreach (var eName in enteredNames)
{ 
    //if eName is not in the list of allFolks throw an exception
    if (!allFolks.Name.Contains(eName))
    throw new Exception ("Name not found");

}
```

What would be the best way to compare each entered name (stored in an array) with the names in the list of type Folks? Is it possible to use Lambda Expression in the example above?

Comment: Other than `allFokes.Name` isn't valid (and how you're doing the Contains comparison), if what you have written works, then it's fine.

Comment: What exactly wrong with code you've posted? There are plenty of ways to change it but at this point the question does not narrow down what you want to fix/improve.

Comment: What are `Folks`, `GetAll`, `inputNames`?  Those all need code defining them.  Some sample data would help as well.

Comment: If `AllFolks` is a big collection, you might want to use something like a `HashSet<T>` rather than a list.  Also, rather than throwing an exception (that doesn't include the name that caused the failure - you'll want it in the message), you may want to gather all the failing names and report it at the end (up to you)

Comment: As @Flydog57 mentions, for large numbers (specifically of `allFolks` elements), this can perform badly as the performance is O(N*M). Using a `HashSet<T>` for `allFolks` is O(N) ...the cost of creating the hashset is O(N) and the scan is O(N).

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] enteredNames = inputNames.Split(',');

foreach (var eName in enteredNames)
{
    if (!allFolks.Any(e => e.Name.Contains(eName.Trim()))
    {
        throw new Exception("Name not found");
    }
}
```

Taking a string of `inputNames` and calling `.Split(',')` will separate the string by each comma and save them into a `string[]`.

Then `if (!allFolks.Any(e => e.Name.Contains(eName)))` will throw the exception if `eName` does not exist within any object in the `List<Folks>`.

Comment: `Count() == 0` can be *inefficient* in case both collections are *large* ones. Imagine, that the workstation can well spend an hour to compute `Count()` being `12345678` and only then compare it with `0`. Put `! ... Any()` instead

Comment: So time complexity of `.Count() == 0` is 0(2n)? What is it for `Any()`? 0(n - 1)?

Comment: Time complexity will be the same in the *worst* case (When `Count == 0`). However, `Any` will beat `Count` in other cases: it returns on the very first occurence when `Count` counts all the occurencies.

Comment: In the cases where a particular `eName.Trim()` is not contained by `allFolks`, `Where().Count()` and `Any()` will be the same - testing every `allFolks.Name` against the `eName`. In the case where it is contained, `Where().Count()` will still do the same but `Any` will exit once the match is found, testing fewer `allFolks`.

Comment: Also, don't use `Trim` in a loop (e.g. `Any`) - the original code did the `Trim` when creating `enteredNames` and that is better.

Answer (score 0):

If I am to infer your requirements, I think you wish to validate a list of names, held as strings, and check to ensure each one matches the `Name` of one of your `Folk` objects.

You can do it with LINQ this way:

```
bool invalid = enteredNames.Any( x => !allFolks.Any( y => y.Name == x) );
```

For a large list of `Folk` objects, you'll get better performance if you extract the unique set of names to a variable of its own.

```
var knownGoodNames = allFolks.Select( x => x.Name ).ToHashSet();
bool invalid = enteredNames.Any( x => !knownGoodNames.Contains(x) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a difficult to asnwer for "what is the best" question: the best in performance, memory, readability?
I suggest using *Linq* in order to query the collections:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Do we have any unknown name (i.e. any namy name except folks' names)?
bool hasUnknownName = inputNames
  .Text
  .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
  .Except(allFolks.Select(folk => folk.Name))
  .Any();

if (hasUnknownName)
  throw ... //TODO: don't throw Exception, but some derived class
```

Linq solution

1. Often is more readable
2. Faster then initial one (if `allFolks` and `inputNames` are large)

**Edit:** As Eric J. puts in the comment below, it's possible to improve performance when `allFolks` is *large* and has *duplicates*. We can, for instance, efficiently compare with (precomputed) unique names only:

```
// We precompute unique names to test 
HashSet<string> uniqueNames = new HashSet<string>(allFolks
  .Select(folk => folk.Name));

... 

bool hasUnknownName = inputNames
  .Text
  .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
  .Any(name => !uniqueNames.Contains(name));

if (hasUnknownName)
  throw ... //TODO: don't throw Exception, but some derived class
```

Comment: If `allFolks` is large, you may get better performance modifying the Except line to `.Except(allFolks.Select(folk => folk.Name).ToHashSet())`

Comment: @EricJ. The code for (.Net Core) `Enumerable.Except` already converts the second parameter (`allFolks.Select()`) to a `HashSet`. Perhaps it should have a special case for when the second parameter is already a `HashSet` however - it currently depends on `new HashSet` special casing which still creates an unneeded copy.

Comment: @NetMage: Good catch.

Comment: @EricJ. As I look more at the code for .Net, I find a lot of the obvious improvements or special cases are already handled in the implementations of e.g. LINQ methods.